# Is it possible to Fire event when Content type added in Shared Documents in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

How to fire event when any **content type added** in shared **document library** ? How to handle this event ?

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility! You can add List Item Event Receivers and bind them to specific Content Type, but I don't think its possible... Here is how you add [List Item Event Receivers on Content Type](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/9dc184f6-878e-44c1-9c0b-35afeba9eb25)

Comment: List Item Event Receivers not work in this case

Comment: I already said that in my comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not handle **content type added** event because there are no such type of event exist in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no events for this.